# Why can't I update my view fragment phoneNumberEditText?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am returning the phone number as a string. I verified it in my logcat. I am trying to use the `phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);` to set the phone number which was defined in the class's scope  `private EditText phoneNumberEditText;` I also tried casting the phone as `CharSequence`

I keep getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mayday.md.common.ContactPickerFragment.onActivityResult(ContactPickerFragment.java:117)
```

Here is the class. I catch the result in an activity and pass the parameters to the onActivityResult.

```
package com.mayday.md.common;

import com.mayday.md.R;
import com.mayday.md.fragment.MessageTextFragment;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT;
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
import static android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class ContactPickerFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST_ID = 100;

    private ImageButton contactPickerButton;
    private EditText phoneNumberEditText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_picker_fragment, container, false);

        contactPickerButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_picker_button);
        phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_text);


        return view;
    }

//    private OnClickListener contactPickerListener = new OnClickListener() {
//        @Override
//        public void onClick(View view) {
//            launchContactPicker(view);
//        }
//    };

//    @Override
//    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
//        contactPickerButton.setOnClickListener(contactPickerListener);
//    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        contactPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 int wizardState = ApplicationSettings.getWizardState(getActivity());
//               if(wizardState != AppConstants.WIZARD_FLAG_HOME_READY){
                     AppConstants.IS_BACK_BUTTON_PRESSED = true;
                     AppConstants.IS_BACK_BUTTON_PRESSED = true;
//               }
                launchContactPicker(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void launchContactPicker(View view) {
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contactPickerIntent.setType(CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST_ID);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, Context context) {
        Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult requestCode "+requestCode);
        Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult resultCode "+resultCode);
        Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult data "+data);

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        String phone = "";
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult id "+id);
                String name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult name "+name);
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    //Query phone here.  Covered next
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    Log.e("WizardActivity", "onActivityResult pCur "+pCur);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        // Do something with phones
                                phone = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult phone "+phone);
                        }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e("ContactPickerFragment", "onActivityResult phone "+phone);

        //phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);
        //phoneNumberEditText.setText((CharSequence)phone);
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat, I X'd out the actual number and name

```
02-22 19:05:32.302  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onUserInteraction
02-22 19:05:32.392  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onUserInteraction
02-22 19:05:32.392  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity.onPause﹕ page = setup-contacts
02-22 19:05:32.392  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/>>>>>>﹕ assert flagRiseFromPause = true
02-22 19:05:32.422  22501-22501/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-22 19:05:33.022  22501-22501/com.mayday.md D/WizardActivity.onStop﹕ page = setup-contacts
02-22 19:05:33.022  22501-22501/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
02-22 19:05:33.022  22501-22501/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-22 19:05:37.512  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult requestCode 65636
02-22 19:05:37.512  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult resultCode -1
02-22 19:05:37.512  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult data Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/2369 flg=0x1 }
02-22 19:05:37.542  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult id 2369
02-22 19:05:37.542  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult name XXXX XXXXX
02-22 19:05:37.542  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onActivityResult pCur android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@42d55b78
02-22 19:05:37.542  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult phone xxxxxxxxxx
02-22 19:05:37.552  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult phone xxxxxxxxxx
02-22 19:05:37.552  22501-22501/com.mayday.md D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-22 19:05:37.552  22501-22501/com.mayday.md W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4172fda0)
02-22 19:05:37.552  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mayday.md, PID: 22501
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65636, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/2369 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.mayday.md/com.mayday.md.WizardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3706)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.mayday.md.common.ContactPickerFragment.onActivityResult(ContactPickerFragment.java:117)
            at com.mayday.md.WizardActivity.onActivityResult(WizardActivity.java:334)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3659)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3706)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line is line 117 in your ContactPickerFragment?

Comment: @mbdavis `phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look the phone from your database is null, you should do the validation/trim the phone before you set into your edit text field.

```
phone = phone==null?"":phone.trim();
phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);
```

Comment: its not null I intentionally hid it with xxx... `02-22 19:05:37.542  22501-22501/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult phone xxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Can u log the phonenumberedittext as well? If tat is null try to set the obj as static

Comment: `phoneNumberEditText null` returns null. You mean set phoneNumberEditText null as static? Also another interesting fact I can set the fragments in the `onCreateView` using `phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);` but not after I get the contact data inside the `onActivityResult`

Comment: Ok, at least we made some progress :-) With static I am able to update one of the 3 contact fields. But not the one I clicked :( I will create a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Just before where you have:

```
//phoneNumberEditText.setText(phone);
//phoneNumberEditText.setText((CharSequence)phone);
```

Try adding the following two lines to check whether your control reference or phone number is somehow becoming null:

```
Log.e("phoneNumberEditText is null:" + phoneNumberEditText == null);
Log.e("phone string is null:" + phone == null);
```

See if either of these are outputting true.

Comment: I know that the phoneNumberEditText object is returning null and the phone variable is retrieving the the correct number.  @zeisuke post helped but I'm getting the number updating the wrong field now. My new post is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680986/how-can-i-put-the-updated-phone-number-into-the-field-i-picked-for-my-android-ap