# How can I put the updated phone number into the field I picked for my Android app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contacts, android-fragmentactivity

How can I put the updated phone number into the field I picked? I have the picker returning the phone number but in the wrong field.

[image]

After picking a contact the phone number is placed in the wrong field.

[image]

My fragment responsible for this contact picker logic is in my repo
https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay/blob/gradle2/app/src/main/java/com/mayday/md/common/ContactPickerFragment.java

How might I refactor this code to put the number in the correct field?

```
02-23 12:47:59.217  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onUserInteraction
02-23 12:47:59.347  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onUserInteraction
02-23 12:47:59.347  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity.onPause﹕ page = setup-contacts
02-23 12:47:59.347  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/>>>>>>﹕ assert flagRiseFromPause = true
02-23 12:47:59.387  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-23 12:48:00.657  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/WizardActivity.onStop﹕ page = setup-contacts
02-23 12:48:00.657  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
02-23 12:48:00.657  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-23 12:48:02.107  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult requestCode 65636
02-23 12:48:02.107  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult resultCode -1
02-23 12:48:02.107  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult data Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/2369 flg=0x1 }
02-23 12:48:02.117  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult id 2369
02-23 12:48:02.117  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult name XXX XXXX
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 598K, 22% free 29241K/37368K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity﹕ onActivityResult pCur android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@4313d048
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult phone xxxxxxxxxx
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult phone xxxxxxxxxx
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/ContactPickerFragment﹕ onActivityResult phoneNumberEditText android.widget.EditText{42c580b0 VFED..CL ........ 0,0-944,156 #7f0b0016 app:id/contact_edit_text}
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/??????﹕ text changed
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/WizardActivity.onStart﹕ page = setup-contacts
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity.onResume﹕ pageId = setup-contacts and flagRiseFromPause = true
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md E/WizardActivity.onResume﹕ back button pressed
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
02-23 12:48:02.147  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
02-23 12:48:02.167  12360-12360/com.mayday.md D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
```

**NEW CLUE** : I notice that the request code returns different values depending on the field I pick: 1st field requestCode 65636, 2nd field requestCode 131172, 3rd field requestCode 196708

Comment: What is the java class used for the provided screenshot? The layout of the fragment link  you provided has only 2 elements in it.

Comment: The methods are inside the class provided `ContactPickerFragment`. `phoneNumberEditText` seems to apply to all three of the phone number fields. I can set them all on creation `onCreateView` by providing phoneNumberEditText.setText('xxxxxxxxxx') . You can see the log output does pertain to this class `onActivityResult phoneNumberEditText` line 118.

Comment: Also I notice that the request code returns different values depending on the field I pick: 1st field requestCode 65636, 2nd field requestCode 131172, 3rd field requestCode 196708

Comment: `fragment_type_interactive_contacts.xml` has the the three fragments listed for the contacts fields. Maybe I can define a static EditView and reference them depending on the requestCode returned?

Comment: i check your github code look like not tally with your screen, because based on the contact_picker_fragment.xml only has one textfield with image icon. did you mind update the latest source?

Comment: My code is up to date. The three fields are listed in https://github.com/jackygrahamez/MayDay/blob/gradle2/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_type_interactive_contacts.xml

Comment: Where do you use `ContactPickerFragment `?

Comment: the layout is MayDay/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_type_interactive_contacts.xml while the class is located MayDay/app/src/main/java/com/mayday/md/common/ContactPickerFragment.java

Comment: I did not manage to fix, but I think I know what's wrong here. The problem is that you use the `contact_picker_fragment` three times. Since the fragment contains the `EditText` with id `contact_edit_text` and you inflate this view three times, the other two references to the `EditText` gets lost. Hence, when you try to add the `phone` to the edit text, it's not found.

Comment: You will need to be able to separate the three `EditText` from each other, and somehow keep the reference to each `EditText` at runtime

Comment: That is sort of what I gathered. Would it help if I got a chat room?

Comment: It would, but I have a meeting in half an hour. Do you have skype?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71791/discussion-between-marcus-and-jack-shultz).

Comment: @JackShultz Hi, I browsed through your project and have identified the problem. If you're still looking for a solution, I can help.

Comment: @Vikram I do need a solution still Marcus and I had a look but we both had to run off to meetings today and could not devote sufficient time. If you got the solution then post it. If it works for me I'll give you the bounty!

Comment: @JackShultz Could we chat?

Comment: sure I'm in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71791/discussion-between-marcus-and-jack-shultz

Comment: Did you manage to fix it already? From the looks of it you are running into a nested fragment issue: Android OS is not smart enough to route an onActivityResult() call back to the correct nested fragment. Something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496682/onactivityresult-not-call-in-the-fragment/28577980#28577980.  But it is a bit hard to analyse as you already changed your code in your repo. :)

Comment: Yes i got a fix from the two commenters here. I was waiting for either to claim bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current setup has `WizardActivity` as the parent activity, `SetupContactsFragment` as a fragment, and `ContactPickerFragment` as a child-fragment. When `ContactPickerFragment` issues a `startActivityForResult(...)` call, `onActivityResult(...)` callback is received in `WizardActivity`.

Problem:

First off, `WizardActivity's` member variable `contactPickerFragment` is never used. It isn't part of your ui. So, calling `contactPickerFragment.onActivityResult(....)` inside `WizardActivity#onActivityResult(...)` does nothing other than print a few log statements. Additionally, the call to `super.onActivityResult(...)` is missing altogether. The correct way would be to check if the request code was issued by `WizardActivity`. If it wasn't, calling the super method will route the `onActivityResult(..)` call to the fragment `SetupContactsFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // currently, WizardActivity does not deal with 
    // any onActivityResult callbacks
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

`SetupContactsFragment` can now receive the `onActivityResult(...)` callback. Still, we need to identify and dispatch `onActivityResult(...)` to the correct child-fragment. One way of doing this is to assign a different `requestCode` to each of the child-fragments. Inside `SetupContactsFragment#onActivityResult(...)`, we iterate over all child-fragments and issue a call to their `onActivityResult(...)` method. Since we have assigned a different `requestCode` to each fragment, only one of these calls will be processed.

However, I don't see why you need three identical child fragments, each holding an input field & a button. These widgets can all be part of `SetupContactsFragemets'` ui. Even if the specifications change from 3 contacts to 10 in the future, you could implement a method that inflates and adds each row multiple times.

In this case, you will need 3 unique `requestCodes`. Based on which `ImageButton` is pressed, a different `requestCode` is used for `startActivityForResult(...)`. Inside `onActivityResult(...)`, the `requestCode` will indicate which `EditText` needs to be updated.

Comment: Can you please help me in following issue. I have been trying hard on this and I see yours this post is related to nested fragments. I will be highly obliged.  Here is the post :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240138/oncreateview-of-nested-fragment-is-not-called